# Magento Product images broken

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

my website [Teentees](http://teentees.in) few days back the site works normally. after some days some product images are broken. so i flushed cache storage, magento cache, and image cache. after that all product images are gone in frontend. how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Provide wrtieable (0777) recusrive permission on `media` folder on root.

As Currently images from your site giving 404 error:

http://teentees.in/media/catalog/product/t/t/ttrncp1507105_1.jpg

Also Please check `.htaccess` file in media folder. If it is exist, try to rename that.

Comment: permissions for media folder given as 0777